# Magento2: Community edition Vs Enterprise edition

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento2, magento-community

I see Magento 2.0 Community edition and  2.0 Enterprise edition is launched. What's the difference between them on functionality level ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Magento 2 Community Releases Notes -http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-2.0.html

Magento 2 Enterprise Release Notes - http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ee-2.0.html

Some of Magento 2 EE highlights is:

- Database scalability (Magento 2 Split Database Solution - https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-split-database.html )
- Advanced search (Solr - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/solr/solr-overview.html )
- Job queue opportunities Message Queues http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/mq/rabbitmq-overview.html)
- Google Tag Manager support
- Extended admin rights management features
- The ability to manage customer attributes and create custom customer attributes
- Scheduled FTP/SFTP transfer via XML
- Dedicated 24/7 support

Learn more at http://magento.com/products/enterprise-edition and https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-enterprise-edition-features.html

Comment: Few specific things:

[Solr search](#http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/solr/solr-overview.html), [Rabbit MQ](#http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/mq/rabbitmq-overview.html), [Split database](#http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html)

Comment: What is the price for Mage 2.0 Enterprise Edition ?

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 Enterprise Edition contains additional modules which are suitable for big shops.

> The Magento Enterprise Edition codebase includes comprehensive scalability enhancements to the database, order management, checkout, catalog, and more. Improvements include asynchronous grid fulfillment, standalone database for checkout, compatibility with MySQL cluster, more concurrent admins for order, and product management and complete separation of store sub-systems.

http://magento.com/blog/technical/magento-2-merchant-beta-release

Comment: Substantiate this. "Additional modules for big shops" - like what.

Answer (score 3):

You can download a full feature list, which describes the unique to Enterprise Edition features, at https://info2.magento.com/rs/318-XBX-392/images/Magento%20Feature%20List%2011.16.2015.pdf

If you reach out to Magento sales, they can share a datasheet that compares Magento Enterprise Edition 2.0 and Community Edition 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Magento Comparison and License Fees: Magento 1 EE, Magento 2 CE, Magento 2 EE https://www.kt-team.de/blog/compare-magento-editions-1ee-vs-2ce-vs-2ee (in English and Russian available).