# Configuring Page Hierarchy

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages

Reading the M2 docs I can see there is meant to be [Page Hierarchy](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/page-hierarchy-configure.html)

However I can't If I go Stores->Settings->Configuration->General->Content Management I don't see any mention of Configuring Page Hierarchy (see screenshot below)

[image: Configuring Page Hierarchy]

Could anyone advise how I enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page hierarchy is an Magento Enterprise feature which is a paid for premium version of the platform. It looks like you're using Magento Community which is the free version and it doesn't include this feature.

If you want to know more about the differences between the two then they are discussed [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90458/magento2-community-edition-vs-enterprise-edition).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/112704)

Comment: Ok I'll expand on it. Fairly self explanatory though :/

Comment: No worries, appreciate the feedback :)